# Entity Framework - Code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Cuando trabajo con EF code first, precisamente cuando las tablas ya creadas tienen datos y necesito crear un nuevo campo o eliminar un nuevo campo. EF me obliga a eliminar los datos que tenía en la tablas para poder agregar o quitar un nuevo campo a una tabla.

Si se tiene una aplicación ya desarrollada con EF y las tablas de la base de datos ya tiene información y se necesita hacer un mantenimiento. ¿Como manejar este tipo de problemas?

Comment: ¿Lograste solucionar el problema?

Comment: @fredyfx Si ya esta solucionado ya cerré este hilo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El proceso es bastante largo y depende de lo que quieras agregar.

[Aquí tienes toda la información](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/data/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx)

Para resumir, debes habilitar tu aplicación para hacer migraciones, ello generara una clase migraciones que es la que puedes personalizar si lo deseas.

También si modificas tu código, ejecutando un comando puedes hacer que la aplicación misma trate de agregar las clases necesarias para la migración. Sin embargo siempre conviene revisar la migración, pues en algunos casos puede que no sea optimo lo que deja.

Comment: Hola si tengo implementado Migrations.

Comment: Y entonces cual es tu problema?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes dos opciones o usar [migraciones](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/migration-in-code-first.aspx), o [pasar de inicializadores](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/turn-off-database-initialization-in-code-first.aspx) y modificar la base de datos a "pelo".

No hay nada mas que hacer, actualmente estoy desarrollando una aplicación con code first, aunque de momento no la he puesto en producción mi idea cara a futuro es usar migraciones, eso si evitando que la aplicación aplique los cambios directamente sobre la base de datos, la idea es capturar el SQL resultante para aplicarlo a mano, creo que de esta forma tendré un mayor control sobre la migración (Update-database -Script).

Saludos,

Comment: Buena información voy a probarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que yo hago es agregar los campos en la BD y después agregarlos al modelos.

Para no perder información en la BD al agregar los campos has que acepten nulos o que tenga un valor default.

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
alter table AlumnosSet
add Apellidos  nvarchar(300) not null  DEFAULT '',
    FechaBaja  datetime null    -- Acepta nulos
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imprimo los valores, tomando solo el campo nombre actualmente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después agrego los campos al modelo con el asistente es fácil:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se actualizó la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los datos en la BD:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejemplo en consola:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De este modo lo resolvería yo, otra forma es eliminar el modelo y volverlo a crear pero ahora con la opción `EF Designer from database`, mucho mas fácil que estar haciendo integraciones.

Comment: Hola Cristina el enfoque de EF que usas es el database first, yo estoy usando el enfoque code first.

Comment: No.. primero diseñe y cree la tabla desde el diseñador del entity.  Despues la enlace con sql y cree la BD desde visual studio.  Después hice lo que te muestro en el ejemplo.  Tal vez te refieres a generar sin el diseñador, todo a pie pues.

Comment: La verdad,yo creo que no hay necesidad de complicarse mucho, la realidad es que sí estas modificando mucho el diseño de la BD es porque no se ha hecho un análisis adecuado,son muy esporádicos ese tipo de cambios cuando se diseña y analiza a profundidad la estructura de los datos.A menos que sea otro tipo de reglas especificas y raras donde se tenga que estar modificando la estructura de la BD constantemente,en muchos años de trabajar en sistemas para diferentes rublos, en mi experiencia no son muy comunes los cambios en las estructuras de las tablas,tal vez agregar nuevas tablas a la BD

Comment: pero pasa que cuando ya se diseño la solución de negocio el cliente, requiere hacer cambios y es ahí donde tengo que ir a rediseñar mi diseño de negocio y hacer los cambios en la base de datos, eso suele pasar, no siempre pero pasa, por lo que veo usas el enfoque model first.

Comment: Ok, entiendo... entonces la solución seria que implementes todo para poder realizar tus migraciones, al parecer no hay camino rápido para hacer lo que necesitas.